# URL Malformed Exception error in Android (java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found)

Tags: android

One of my URL is like the following: "h--p://www.test.com/*/*/rss.xml"

When I run the following code:

```
private String RSSFEEDURL = Uri.encode("h--p://www.test.com/path/*/*/rss.xml");
URL url = null;
        
try {
  url = new URL(xml);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
   e1.printStackTrace();
   }
```

I am getting "java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found: http%3A%2F%2Ftest.com%2Fpath%2F*%2F*%2Frss.xml"

I have already done Uri encode as shown above. Any idea, what is causing this issue and how I could resolve it?

Comment: Is that your actual Uri? Because that doesn't look like a valid Uri? Or is that just to avoid some form of url-detection here? And second: I believe it is encoding the actual part you don't want encoded (like the `:`) so you could put that stuff IN an Uri, not to just 'make it an uri'.

Comment: @Nanne I just put in a dummy url here for sample. U mean like h--p://www.test.com + Uri.encode("/path/*/*/rss.xml")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you call `new URL` the thing you put in there should be a valid URL.

You're putting this in there: `http%3A%2F%2Ftest.com%2Fpath%2F*%2F*%2Frss.xml`, and that's not a valid URL, so the exception is expected.

You shouldn't encode your whole URL.